# Express retriggering API endpoint on request timeouts

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, nginx

**Context:**
My Express.js web server is currently serving an API which wraps a SOAP service (some legacy service which I can't change). The SOAP service takes a dynamic number of items to process and takes about 1.5 seconds to process each request. The Nginx server has a timeout of 60 seconds.

**Problem:**
For a request to this API which e.g. lets say takes more than 60 seconds to complete, I am observing that the service is getting re-triggered automatically (I am assuming by Express.js). So if in the original request I was expecting to insert lets say 50 records to a table, now due to the re-triggering of the API I am ending up with 100 records inserted (duplication).

Here is a skeleton/sample of log that kind of shows the issue: (sensitive info stripped)

```
January 10, 2022 15:35:44 [... ee905] - Starting myAwesomeAPI()  <-- Original API trigger
January 10, 2022 15:36:44 [... ff870] - Starting myAwesomeAPI()  <-- Re-trigger happens
January 10, 2022 15:36:54 [... ee905] - Completed myAwesomeAPI() <-- Original API ends (inserts 50 records in the table)
January 10, 2022 15:37:54 [... ff870] - Completed myAwesomeAPI() <-- Re-triggered API ends (inserting another 50 records in the table resulting in duplication)
```

**What I have tried:**
To reproduce the issue and check if the re-triggering can be independent of nginx. With the Nginx timeout set to 60 seconds, I changed my Express server's timeout to 10 seconds and 15 items to process (to force timeout before processing can be complete) using this:

```
const express = require("express")
const server = express()
server.setTimeout(10000)  <-- sets all requests to have a 10 seconds timeout

// myAwesomeAPI code
```

Testing showed that after 10 seconds, the timeout "did" re-trigger the API and the 15 items were duplicated (I saw 30 records inserted). So this tells me that the API is getting re-triggered by Express.js.

**Question(s):**

1. How to stop the re-trigger from happening, is there an express server configuration to enable/disable the auto re-triggering on timeout?

**Solutions & Ideas:**

1. Since the `max items = 100` (set by team), increasing the Nginx and Express.js timeout to 300 seconds should be a quick but dirty fix. I understand that tying async API calls to some approximation of time is pure foolishness (tell me about trying to explain this to other engineers in my team ;-p), so I would like to avoid this approach.
2. Create a composite key with some combination of columns and enforce the insert restrictions on the table. Combine this with checking if the composite key is already inserted/present in the table and decide to skip/insert. This approach seems a bit better .
3. Another approach can be to respond back to the API call immediately on receipt (which will close the request) and then continue with the request processing. Something like this (inspiration): https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3275-you-can-continue-to-process-an-express-js-request-after-the-client-response-has-been-sent.htm.

   This will make me independent of platform's timeout settings but will take away the real-time nature of the response being delivered with statuses for different items and add a bit more complexity of tracking the request statuses via other lookups etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the ability to alter the front end you can add a transaction ID to it. Store the transaction routine in an object linked to the transaction ID, then if you get an API request for an ongoing transaction you can refer to the ongoing transaction.

Something like this:

```js
let transactions = {};

router.get('/myapi', async (req,res,next) => {
  try {
    let {transactionID} = req.params;
    delete(req.params.transactionID);
    let transaction = transactions[transactionID];
    if(!transaction) {
      transaction = (async () => {
        let ret = await SOAPCall(req.params);
        // hold onto the transaction for some period of time
        let to = setTimeout(()=>{
          delete(transactions[transactionID]);
        }, 5000);
        to.detach(); // don't hold up process exit
        return ret;
      })();
      transactions[transactionID] = transaction;
    } 
    let ret = await transaction;
    res.json(ret);
  }
  catch(err) { next(err) }
});
```